# Finding the upper bound in this question?

Tags: probability

If we consider the top 30 earning actors, their mean salary was about
30 million dollars, and the SD of these 30 salaries was about 15 million dollars. Can you give an upper bound on the
fraction of the actors on this list that made at least 45 million dollars?

I considered using the Chebyshev's theorem, but since 45 million is just 1 SD above the mean, we cannot apply Chebyshev's theorem right here? Therefore we cannot give an upper bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume
$$x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_{30}$$
where $x_k$ is the dollar amount, in millions, earned by the $k$-th actor.

Assume the sequence $(x_k)$ has mean $\mu=30$, and standard deviation $\sigma=15$.

From $\mu=30$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{30} x_k = 900$$
and from $\sigma=15$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{30} (x_k-30)^2 = 6750$$

Let $p$ be the number of actors from the given set whose earnings are at least $45$ million dollars.

Then $p=15$ is possible, since if $15$ actors each earn exactly $45$ million dollars, and the other $15$ actors each earn exactly $15$ million dollars, we get $\mu=30$, and $\sigma=15$.

**Claim:**$\;p\ge 16$ is not possible.

Suppose $p\ge 16$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&\sum_{k=1}^{30} x_k = 900\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k+(16)(45) \le 900\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k\le 180\\[20pt]
\text{and}\;\;&\sum_{k=1}^{30} (x_k-30)^2 = 6750\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} (x_k-30)^2 + (16)(15^2) \le 6750\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} (x_k-30)^2 \le 3150\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} (x_k^2-60x_k+30^2) \le 3150\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k+\sum_{k=1}^{14} 30^2 \le 3150\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k+(14)(30^2) \le 3150\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k\le -9450\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-(60)(180)\le -9450\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2 \le 1350\\[20pt]
\text{Then}\;\;&\left(\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k\right)^{\!2}\le (14)\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2
\qquad\text{[by Cauchy-Schwarz]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\left(\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k\right)^{\!2}\le (14)(1350)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k < 138\\[20pt]
\text{But then}\;\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-60\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k\le -9450\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2-(60)(138) < -9450\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^{14} x_k^2 < -1170\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

Thus, as claimed, $p=16$ is not possible.

It follows that the maximum possible ratio is ${\large{\frac{15}{30}}}={\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.